# How to fix SQL Server stored procedure timeout - partially complete when called from VBS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have VBS called stored procedures starting but not completing and returning query timeout messages to the application.

We are on SQL Server 2008 SP2 release 1, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

This is not an issue in production, but in dev we have VBS scripts associated with the DrillThrough database producing:

> VBS<105,4> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Query timeout expired.

These scripts are automated on the application server side. The stored procedure queries run fine in SSMS but **do take over 40 seconds**.

ALL the scripts are all set not to timeout:

```
conn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
conn.CommandTimeout = 0
```

The OLEDB login is the dbo. The only scripts failing are on the DrillThrough database. The failing scripts use more than one database and functions in the DrillThrough database to gather data in temp tables to update the actual drill through table.

There is one nightly process that is completing on the DrillThrough database where the stored procedure runs in about 2 seconds. It does not use any functions but does compare data from two records pulled from two other databases before writing the difference to a table.

I have compared the scripts and they are set up the same except for the stored procedures they call.

I updated statistics on the tables just in case. The query still timed out on the application side, and actually took a little longer to run in SSMS.

The SQL Server remote connections is set to 0 for no timeout.

It definitely gets into the procedure because it truncates the tables, bulk loads the holding table and deletes from the actual drill through table based on the holding table data and creates the first temp table but it is not completing and is dropping out somehow.

Again, the stored procedure runs fine in SSMS all the way through.

Everyone refers back to the SQL Server setting and the `ConnectionTimeout` and `CommandTimeout`. No one seems to be experiencing a situation where the stored procedure starts but doesn’t complete.

Other things I’ve tried with the same results:

- Adding ‘With Recompile’ to the stored procedure
- Setting an actual timeout time in the VB Script
- I have tuned the query as much as I can
- I can't get a faster development server.

Comment: When a timeout occurs during execution, the client API sends an attention signal to SQL Server to cancel the executing query.  This will result in partial stored proc execution.  Verify the CommandTimeout property is set to zero on property on all Connection and Command objects.

Comment: <105,4> is the location inside your script where this is occurring (line and column I think). Is it just one spot it occurs at or is it many? Does it happen to time out after exactly 30 seconds? If so you definitely need to triple check that CommandTimeout is set. If you have large scripts I suggest you try to reproduce with the smallest amount of code. (and post it here). Also it's a long shot but beware of On `On Error Resume Next` hiding the real error